# Sorting datetime object in a list of tuples

Tags: python

i have a list of tuples which is like following

```
[('John', datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 18, 18)), ('Adam', datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 18, 18), ('Adam', datetime.datetime(2001, 05, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2002, 09, 27, 18, 18)) ('Adam', datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 18, 18))]
```

How can i sort this list based on the datetime object, basically its in the format `Name,From date, To date`

Comment: So you want the earliest dates first?

Comment: Yes need earlier dates first

Comment: That is from date or to date?

Comment: Earlier date is from date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `key` parameter of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) on `from_date`:

```
import datetime

data = [('John', datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 18, 18)),
        ('Adam', datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 18, 18)),
        ('Adam', datetime.datetime(2001,  5, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2002,  9, 27, 18, 18)),
        ('Adam', datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 18, 18))]


result = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1])

for e in result:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
('Adam', datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2002, 9, 27, 18, 18))
('Adam', datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 18, 18))
('John', datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 18, 18))
('Adam', datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 18, 18), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 18, 18))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got the question right. But, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Since you can compare DateTime objects with each other, the only thing remaining to do is to ask the sorted function to sort based on them (in this case the second element of each tuple).